# How to pull out images with muuri library and ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

In my project I am trying to show a grid container with images, this using muuri library, and I am trying to pull out the images from a database using simple vanila javascript, php and ajax on it. The problem with this is that only shows the last image stored in the table in the database. This is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vistas/css/styles.css">
    <title>Grid</title>


<body>

    <div class="container">
        <section class="grid">
    </section>
    </div>
    
    <script> 
    const grid = new Muuri('.grid');
           
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET','model/images.php',true);
    xhr.onload = function(){
        if(this.status == 200){
        
            var images = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            
            var outPut1 = '';
            for(var i in images){
                outPut1 += '<div class="item"><div class="item-content"><img src="'+images[i].matImage+'" alt=""></div></div>';
    
            }
            document.getElementById('grid').innerHTML = outPut1;  
      
        }
    }
    xhr.send();   
    </script>
             
  </body>
</html>
```

As you can see I am trying to get the images from the images.php file and this file contains the main query to fetch the records from the database and encodes the result in json format...

```
<?php
$conexion = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','dbImages');

$query = "SELECT * FROM images";

$result = mysqli_query($conexion,$query);

$images = mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

echo json_encode($images);
```

Here it's my css code too.

```
.grid{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    opacity:0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s linear 1s;
}

.grid .item{
    position: absolute;
    display:block;
    padding:0;
    margin:10px;
    width: calc(33.333333% - 20px);
}

.grid .item-content{
    position:relative;
}

.grid .item img{
    width:100%;
    cursor:pointer;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

I've been working with this so long , and I haven't solve it, it only shows the last image on the table on the database and I would like to do it with a library like this because I want they would be draggagle.

If there is a better idea of how to do this i would be thankful...

Comment: Have you tried adding `const grid = new Muuri('.grid');` after `document.getElementById('grid').innerHTML = outPut1;`? That way the Murri is created after the new photos were added to the DOM. Or using `grid.add('<div class="item"><div class="item-content"><img src="'+images[i].matImage+'" alt=""></div></div>');`

Comment: Where do you include this library? What errors do you get?

Comment: It works! adding const grid = new Muuri('.grid'); after document.getElementById('grid').innerHTML = outPut1; Thank you so much , I will continue now , probably I will get more errors like this